# Babel doesn't transpile bind expressions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-loader

In our project we are using VueJS, and we have a lot of code, which looks like this:

`` <template lang="jade">
  div(v-bind:class='`type-${type}`') Hello world!
</template> ``

But, it doesn't work in IE 11, because string templates feature is not supported in IE, and it seems Babel unable to transpile this string, because interpretation of it involves some VueJS magic and Babel sees it as a string. Here is an error message:

[image]

Is there any workaround for this issue, besides rewriting all such code by hands?

We are using Vue 1.0, and `vue-loader` for single-file components support, configuration looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you have installed all babel dependencies ? (babel-core, babel-loader etc). Also are you using webpack or browserfiy ?

Comment: @Belmin I am using webpack. And yes, I have all these dependencies in my package.json.

Comment: Did you set babel-loader in webpack config like this      ` {
        test:     /\.js$/,
        loader:   'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }, ` ? Btw you can set es2015 presets with .babelrc file

Comment: @Belmin, No, because we use Single Page Components (https://vuejs.org/guide/single-file-components.html), so `vue-loader` need to work only for *.vue files. Webpack actually works fine, it transpiles our code correcly. Babel doesn't work only for bind-expressions.

Comment: Does it work with classic html implementation?

Comment: @El_Matella No, it doesn't work either

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? I'm using Vue and Babel with Gulp and neither bind, call, nor apply work inside of a method when calling a function from an imported file.

Comment: Ahh figured it out.  The function in question is utilizing an arrow function, which will not work with bind, call, or apply.